# HtmlUnit on Android

Tags: android

I have been coding a web scraping application on Android, using HtmlUnit.
But, when I build the app, the build error occur "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1".
So, how do I build the android app using HtmlUnit? please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this, and saw a lot of other errors triggered by XML-related jars, including this:

```
[2011-05-20 12:57:50 - Android Hello] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
```

The problem went away after I removed the `xalan`, `xercesImpl` and `xml-apis` jars from the project (I usually include them with any projects using HtmlUnit on the desktop).   Presumably they are colliding with the versions included in the SDK.