# Is there a tool like mechanize for Android?

Tags: android, mechanize

I'm creating an Android app which must do some web surfing in the background in order to provide a service to the user.

The site I must connect to has no API, it only provides standard HTTP access, with extensive cookie usage but (luckily for me) not much Javascript code.

I wonder if there is a library which behaves like python mechanize for Android, or if it's possible to use mechanize itself in the Android app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure it'll work in Android, but being Java-based, [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is probably worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, and it looks like it _can_ work on Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882280/htmlunit-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize has been ported to Java, and does run in Android:

http://gistlabs.com/software/mechanize-for-java/