# screen scraping on android phone using (ICS)

Tags: java, android, screen-scraping, watin, watir

I am looking to implement simple automation which requires screen scraping for an android (ICS) phone.

What are the options, frameworks, libraries available?

I have been using WATIN on .NET and found it very powerful and yet easy to use,
A Java version of WATIN, WATIR - is it a good choice for web screenscraping / automation for the Android platform?

Comment: See this previous [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773655/is-there-a-tool-like-mechanize-for-android).

Comment: watir is actually a ruby library, and watin is a .net version of it, not the other way around.

Comment: There is in fact a Java port of Watir - http://watij.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver) or [selenium-webdriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) Ruby gems to drive real browsers in Android emulators or real Android devices. Of course, if you are not a Ruby person, you can do the same from another language. More information: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver

Answer (score 1):

Using RESTful API enables you to extract data with minimum coding effort. Here are some links you might be interested in.

Calling a REST web service from Android
http://timewasted.net/?p=127

Synthetics Web
http://www.syntheticsweb.com/